# Invoke CNA on iOS8 device

Tags: ios8, raspberry-pi, wifi, captivenetwork

I am working on a network controller based on Raspberry Pi 2. I have nicely working WiFi AP, DHCP server, captive portal (via DNSmasq) and a web server. The unit is fully offline, no internet access is available.

My only problem now is that users need to initiate interaction by running their browser and typing in a random domain so they are served my content.

I was searching the internet for a way to make my iPhone initiate captive network assistant, but couldn't find a way to do so on iOS 8.

Given that my network is offline with no access to the internet it is clear to me that my iPhone detected a captive portal as it presumably pings many websites in order to determine it's online status. Why doesn't it display my login screen automatically?